# Understanding regex flags and Bitwise operators

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-re

I'm trying to understand how all the regex flags and bitwise tie together. The only thing I can really find related to this is in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.compile) where it says you can use Bitwise or the '|' operator. I've always used that operator when using flags in the past, but I wanna know how it works and what is the advantage of using the other operators such as (&, ^, ~, >>, <<)

From my understanding, each flag represents a value?

```
print('{:>15} = {}'.format('re.ASCII',      int(re.ASCII)))
print('{:>15} = {}'.format('re.DEBUG',      int(re.DEBUG)))
print('{:>15} = {}'.format('re.IGNORECASE', int(re.IGNORECASE)))
print('{:>15} = {}'.format('re.LOCALE',     int(re.LOCALE)))
print('{:>15} = {}'.format('re.MULTILINE',  int(re.MULTILINE)))
print('{:>15} = {}'.format('re.DOTALL',     int(re.DOTALL)))
print('{:>15} = {}'.format('re.VERBOSE',    int(re.VERBOSE)))

>       re.ASCII = 256
>       re.DEBUG = 128
>  re.IGNORECASE = 2
>      re.LOCALE = 4
>   re.MULTILINE = 8
>      re.DOTALL = 16
>     re.VERBOSE = 64
```

What would be the difference in these examples:

```
re.compile('[\w]+', flags=(re.IGNORECASE | re.MULTILINE)
re.compile('[\w]+', flags=(re.IGNORECASE & re.MULTILINE)
re.compile('[\w]+', flags=(re.IGNORECASE ^ re.MULTILINE)
or
re.compile('[\w]+', flags=(re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)
re.compile('[\w]+', flags=(re.DOTALL & re.MULTILINE)
re.compile('[\w]+', flags=(re.DOTALL ^ re.MULTILINE)
```

*Bitwise table for reference:*

| Operator | Example | Meaning |
| --- | --- | --- |
| & | a & b | Bitwise AND |
| | | a | b | Bitwise OR |
| ^ | a ^ b | Bitwise XOR (exclusive OR) |
| ~ | ~a | Bitwise NOT |
| << | a << n | Bitwise left shift |
| >> | a >> n | Bitwise right shift |

Comment: This is just bitwise operations. Using these particular values the result of `&` is always zero as no two flags share the same bits set to 1. `^` will turn off any flags that appear an even number of times in a multi-term expression. `~` will set every flag not set and removes every flag set. shifting here is really meaningless as it turns flags into other flags. In short, when using bit flags only using `|` makes logical sense here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just common practice to use flags.
In python, C++ programs, maybe others too, flags are usually used in this kind of style. Let me give you an example.

```
re.compile('[\w]+', flags=(re.IGNORECASE | re.MULTILINE)
```

When you set the flags like above, this means that you want to apply both this two settings, namely IGNORECASE and MULTILINE.

I think you feel confused why this would apply both two settings. This is because python reinterpreter is highly possible to handle this like below:

```
if flags & re.IGNORECASE:
    handle_in_ignorecase_way()

if flags & re.MULTILINE:
    handle_in_multiline_way()
```

This is why flags are set usually in patterns like 1, 2, 4, 8, etc. because reinterpreter can easily handle them using & and | when users give multiple flags. The flags are placed in different bit positions, and they could be parsed by simple bit hacks.